# How to get Quantities of selected object?

Tags: autodesk-forge

how to get Quantities of selected object, like you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXDgz.jpg  ?
@PetrBroz helped me to get Properties of selected object (He's example is here: 
) but I also need to get Quantities: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXDgz.jpg
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to traverse the *instance tree* to find the parent you're interested in. In your example, it would be something like this:

```
const ids = viewer.getSelection();
if (ids.length > 0) {
    const instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
    let id = ids[0];
    id = instanceTree.getNodeParentId(id);
    id = instanceTree.getNodeParentId(id);
    id = instanceTree.getNodeParentId(id);
    // Or better, traverse the parents in a while loop until you find one that matches your requirements
    viewer.getProperties(id, function(props) {
        console.log(props);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works well but only for Wall :(  
If you take a look here: https://imgur.com/qEobPKb you will see what I mean - Window have 5 parents (Wall only 3) and it does not work well. "Quantities" is one category, please check this: https://imgur.com/S1RAzhd and basically I need somehow to iterate upwards (starting from clicked object) until I find first parent who have Category named "Quantities". Do you have idea how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: I see... in that case you'll probably need to find the "interesting" nodes beforehand and store them yourself. The viewer provides several methods that can help with that, for example, [Viewer3D.prototype.search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames) method. You can use it to find all objects with some specific text in their properties, store all the resulting IDs, and then when you're traversing the instance tree, you'd go upwards until you find a parent with one of those IDs.

Comment: Thank you again but I'm not sure how to do that? Can you please create some example using your previous example http://jsfiddle.net/s47vy5u3/3 ? I'm new in this (and in JavaScript) so I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s47vy5u3/5. I'd also encourage you to look at the existing blog articles related to this topic, for example, https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/getbulkproperties-method, or https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/property-based-selection-isolation.

Comment: Hello again, since today, your example does not work (http://jsfiddle.net/s47vy5u3/5) - it give me 404 error. Can you please check? Thank you.